# Magento Share Wishlist button not working

Tags: php, magento, share

I have following code in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/button/share.phtml

```
<?php if($this->getWishlist()->getItemsCount()): ?>
<button type="submit" name="save_and_share" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share Wishlist') ?>" class="button btn-share"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Share Wishlist') ?></span></span></button>
```

But clicking on Share Wishlist button doesn't do anything. It doesn't update the count or opens up the share wishlist page.  It simply redirects to same wishlist page. Do I have to configure something in admin to make it work? Or something wrong with the code?

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone? Kinda stuck at this one..

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but i got the same problem, and the cause was having eliminated the Comment textarea from the product list in the wishlist.
Restoring the textarea and setting it `display: none` via css solved the "share wishlist" problem, while having no comment textarea showed.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, but you just saved me a ton of time. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is in app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php Line 362, it checks if the request is POST and that it contains the value for "description".
I added this:
else if($post && isset($post['save_and_share']))
        {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/share', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
            return;
        }

Comment: can you please share the file with location